# Split Partition of a table

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

We have a table of approx. 2 billion records and it consist of data from 2007 to till date.

Table is interval daily partitioned.

There exists one partition which consists of data prior to 2016 and it is having approx. 1.5 billion records.

We want to split that partition into daily partition but it is too slow.

Taking 3 hours to split 3 months data and we need to split 9 years data.

Please provide the effective way to accomplish that task.

Comment: Create a new table, copy the data into this separate table, then truncate old partitions, split them and insert the data back

Comment: Please use universal measurements instead of local words. A lot of people aren't going to know what *crore records* are, and that will just confuse them.

Comment: Steps we followed

1. Renamed the original table
2. Created New table with all partitions
3. Inserting back data from renamed table to new partitioned table

But we stuck in 3rd step

Answer (score 0):

Each split needs to write all of the records in the source partition into 2 new ones. Thus you only want to this once.

If you are on a recent version of Oracle, then split allows multiple partitions in a single pass, eg

```
ALTER TABLE sales SPLIT PARTITION SALES_2002 INTO (
 PARTITION SALES_JAN_2002 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-FEB-2002','DD-MON-YYYY')),
 PARTITION SALES_FEB_2002 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-MAR-2002','DD-MON-YYYY')),
 ...
 ...
 PARTITION SALES_DEC_2002);
```

If you are on an older release, then you cant do that, which means you would be better off using DBMS_REDEFINITION to achieve the entire process with one pass through the table.

Comment: Yes that's correct but its taking a lot of time for even one year ( Approx. 10 hours) and we need to split partition 10 years.

Comment: is the table indexed? Better to set them to unusable and rebuild afterrwards. And dont forget parallelism.  And you didn't mention if you're doing multi or single partition